# Trying to locate a story about deep space astronauts appearing back on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space, astronauts

I don't have much details, read the story a long time ago, but the gist is - in a deep space expedition, astronauts became homesick to such degree - they were able to transport back to earth through sheer force of will, instantaneously. They missed Earth so much, they wished to be back home with such a force - their wish became reality.

Comment: Any idea how old the story might be? Is it a short story or a full book/novel?

Comment: Sounds a little like one of the short stories from the Martian chronicles by Ray Bradbury minus the deep space. Of course they did not really travel home... When they landed on Mars they thought they were home. Certainly a different story.

Comment: It wasn't a full blown novel, I don't recall exact length, but definitely not long. Yes it has a recollection of a short story. I read it back in the 90s, but I have a feeling it had a "classic" feel to it even back then a feel of 60s sci-fi

Comment: I'm reminded of Cordwainer Smith's "Drunkboat", But it was a single astronaut, and he returned for love (for Elizabeth!). It was "an ancient rocket with the old, old writing, mysterious letters printed all over the machine," "--I and O and M for 'Instrumentality of Mankind' written on it good and sharp."

Comment: Did the astronauts return with or without their spaceship?

Comment: @user14111 yes, they were really far away at that time, communication with Earth becoming very spotty, almost impossible and they began to disappear from the ship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some deep digging I found it. It's a short story by Russian sci-fi writer Victor Kolupaev called *For love of Earth*. I've seen only one English translation – in a short story collection [Hermit's swing](https://openlibrary.org/books/OL4104210M/Hermit%27s_swing).

It begins with

> A dazzling blue light flared on the 3-D television wall for an instant, flickered, and, spreading out slowly, filled the room. Espas settled down a bit more comfortably in a deep, leather armchair and stretched his legs. He always enjoyed watching the latest news. Holographic images transported him to the four corners of the Earth, to the depths of oceans and into endless Space. He felt himself a participant in events that he could never really be a part of.

And ends with

> All has seen Earth again, all except Verona….
>
> “Verona,” said Roid, “tomorrow we’re sending you down for a week. You will see Earth.”
>
> But the following day they missed the region where wave guides former. Verona did not see Earth, but she took it very well. Her cremates hardly knew what to say to her. Then Roid went over to her and kissed her.
>
> “This kiss is from your mother,” he said.
>
> For this he had flown to the Apennines.
>
> *Prometheus* sped on towards Blue Star.

Answer (score 3):

James Tiptree Jr's [The Man Who Walked Home](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?43676)  (etext [here](http://www.baenebooks.com/chapters/9781625791542/9781625791542___2.htm)) sounds like a close match.

Comment: While we have an accept answer, why did you think yours was a good answer?

Comment: @SeanDuggan: Perhaps because it was posted four days before the accepted one?

Comment: {nods} Nevertheless, it never hurts to have a quick summary of how it matches. That way, people looking for a similar story may find the right one in this one.